# will html tag library in struts 1.2 support internetr explorer 9

Tags: java, css, struts-1

I am using struts 1.2 to  developing an application form which supports all browsers except safari and internet explorer 9 is there any issues with the browsers?

Also alignment issues in the above browsers only can any body help?

Answer (score 0):

The Struts 1 form tags emit pure HTML; there's no "compatibility" involved.

Any "alignment" issues are CSS-related.